# Smooth colors in geom_line

Tags: r, colors, ggplot2

Using `ggplot2`, I would like color lines "smoothly" in a plot where I have only few datapoints. As is, the scales I tried (e.g. `scale_color_gradient2`) do not seem to interpolate colors, but instead color segments monochromatically.

Code example:

```
ggplot(data.frame(x=1:5)) + geom_line(aes(x=x, y=x, color=x), size=3) + 
   scale_color_gradient2()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could increase the amount of points between 1 and 5:

```
df <- data.frame(x=seq(1,5,0.001))

ggplot(df) + geom_line(aes(x=x, y=x, color=x), size=3) + 
   scale_color_gradient2()
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Ideally I would like a method which does not require changing the data. In fact, the reason why I use few points is that I have many curves (on the same plot), so adding many points will make ggplot blow up.