# r ggplot non-linear gradient alpha

Tags: r, ggplot2

Take the following data

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3),
                 cond = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2),
                 Time = c(1,2,1,2,1,2),
                 State  = c("Empty", "Empty", "Empty", "Full", "Full", "Empty"),
                 eye = c(2, -3, -2, 1, 0, -2),
                 combination = c(1, 1,2, 2, 3, 3))
```

and the plot

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = Time, y = eye)) +
  geom_point(aes(shape=State), size = 3.5) +
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(13,15)) +  
  geom_line(aes(group=ID, color = Time, alpha = State), size = 5) +
    
  theme(legend.title=element_blank(),
        axis.title.x=element_text(size = 12),
        axis.title.y=element_text(size = 12),
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 15),
        axis.text.x= element_text(color = "black"),
        axis.text.y= element_text(color = "black"),
        axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
        plot.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"))
```

which produces

[image]

my problem is

1. this gives the lines different alphas, but I want the lines to have gradient alpha. Specifically, I need the line that goes between 'empty' and 'full' state to start with low alpha and end with high alpha, and the line that goes from 'full' to 'empty' to start with high alpha and end with low alpha. (the line that goes from 'low' to 'low' is okay as it is in the example).
2. On the x-axis, instead of starting at x = 1 and ending at x = 2, I want the 'empty' to 'full' line to start at 1.25 and then 'fade in' to end at 2, and I want the 'full' to 'empty' line to start at 1.00 and 'fade out' to end at 1.75.

I have been hassling with this problem for a while now, any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I think the main way I've seen to do this in the past is to interpolate more data between your two end points and then make the gradient based on those values. You can see an example [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17794763/2461552), for example.

Comment: Yeah I told him that the last time he asked the same question.

Comment: See answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68068302/r-scale-alpha-not-continuous/68124048#68124048... This seems like duplicate question.

Comment: An answer to this problem can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68068302/r-scale-alpha-not-continuous/68124048#68124048